# How to pass a javascript (js) Map to spring boot Controller?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've a Java Script map having key value pairs which i Need to send to spring boot contoller   :--

Example :--

```js
 var myMap = new Map();
     myMap.set('1', 'value1');
     myMap.set('2', 'value2');
```

I'm not able to get this JavaScript (js) map in my spring boot controller.
To my best practice I'm trying to get this map in java's HashMap or Map.
A help is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: convert it to JSON and post it through AJAX..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I've figured out the solution :-

```
var myMap = new Map();
         myMap.set('1', 'value1');
         myMap.set('2', 'value2');
         myMap.set('3', 'value3');
         myMap.set('4', 'value4');

         //Making JS Map compatible for JSON.Stringify
         const out = Object.create(null)
         myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
          if (value instanceof Map) {
            out[key] = map_to_object(value)

          }
          else {
            out[key] = value
          }
        })
```

---

```
$.ajax({
     type : "POST",
     url :  "/yourURL",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data : JSON.stringify(myMap) //......
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourURL", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> reqControl(@RequestBody Map<String,<String> myMap) {
       //  further code.   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

```
var myMap = {};
myMap["names"] = ["Alex"];
myMap["fruit"]  = ["Apple"];
```

Modify javascript code to use Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
     type : "POST",
     url :  "/reqURL",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data : JSON.stringify(myMap) // .....
```

Controller code like below:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/reqURL", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> reqControl(@RequestBody Map<String, List<String>> myMap) {
       // do something with parameters ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Amit For Responding, The above Suggestion is absolutely correct However, JSON.stringify isn't working as it is Printing --  "{}" on browser's console and on spring controller ( "{}") .

Comment: How `{}` is coming, JSON structure need to be enclosed with `{}`, share a sample JSON, is Spring Controller complaining and not able to convert to aMap?

Comment: This solution does/will not work!! Maps are handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I pass the map to a servlet but maybe it can help someone:

---

```
    $.ajax({
    ...
    data: { 
     "MY_MAP": JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(myMap))
    },
    ...
```

---

```
String myMapString = parameters.get("MY_MAP");
Map<String, String> myMap = new Gson().fromJson(myMapString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {}.getType());
```