# How to pass Array or Map instead of single value with the value of a submit button

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf form and working with spring boot project. It has a iteration with a list inside the form. I want to send deferent submits according to the each items in the list. I can send single value to the back end via submit button value. But it is not enough to identify which sumbit button was clicked. Thats why I want to send complex (list , map , object or array) value with the submit button value.

here is my current submit button.

```
<button type="submit" name='action' th:value="${traveller}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always combine a collection of values into a ordinary string by concat the values with a delimiter in between.

List ["a", "b", "c"] could be "a$b$c". It's easy to restore the list at the controller.

Same goes for Dictionaries/Maps. ["a" : 3, "b" : 4, "c" : 6] can be "a:3$b:4$c:6".

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue where I was trying to send JavaScript map to Spring boot Controller.
Here's the solution for that, hope it helps :--

[How to pass a javascript (js) Map to spring boot Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509356/how-to-pass-a-javascript-js-map-to-spring-boot-controller)

Comment: That's smart. But the problem I see is that you have to solve @Nwn's specific problem with javasscript. With that approach you can't submit the form directly. You have to get all values from the form in javascript, create a ajax-request and replace the whole page with the reponse (in the specific problem).

Comment: @Flocke you're right mate,  the issue with this approach is that he needs to set all the form's values  in Javascript to send it further.
Unfortunately that wasn't the case for me cz  I only  need JS map from thyemleaf page to controller.