# How to Pass Map object form angular 6 to Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, angular6

Hi  I am struggling to pass direct map object form angular to spring boot .Is it possible?

My requirement is to pass `Map<String,String> testMap`  this map from Angular6 to spring boot.

My angular code and console output:
[image]
Spring boot code and result:
[image]

Finally  I am getting angular map count is 2 and spring boot that is 0 count.Please help me

Answer (score 1):

please refer to this link . I think map should be stringify JSON.stringify(map) before posting.
[How to pass a javascript (js) Map to spring boot Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509356/how-to-pass-a-javascript-js-map-to-spring-boot-controller)